# ImportError: No module named package using pip in Docker

Tags: docker, cron, pip, dockerfile, python-3.4

I'm using Docker to build my application. I'm using pip to install the packages from `requirements.txt` but the package is not including in the build.

```
FROM python:3.4
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip python-pip\
    cron \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    python3-dev \
    python3-setuptools \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install sendgrid
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENV CONFIG_ENV .env
ADD validator-cron /etc/cron.d/validator-cron-job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/validator-cron-job
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

I'm installing `sendgrid` using pip but I'm getting `ImportError: no module found error`.

Comment: Is your error message `ImportError: No module named package` or `ImportError: no module found error`? What's the content of `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.
It is coming because of the python path.